# Exercise problem on complex integration

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to show that the value of integral $\frac{i}{4- \pi}\int_{C} \frac{1}{z \cos z} = 2$, where C  is circle: |z| = 4.

I am solving this problem by using Cauchy residue theorem as follows.

Here the singularities of the function are given by putting $z \cos z = 0$. This implies that singular points $z = 0,  \pi/2 , -\pi/2$ are the only singular points and they are also the simple poles of the given function lying inside the given curve $C$.

Residue $(f(z), 0) = 1/ (z \cos z)^\prime_{z = 0}$ = $1$.

Residue $(f(z), \pi/2) = 1/ (z \cos z)^\prime_{z = \pi/2}$ = $-\pi/2$.

Residue $(f(z), -\pi/2) = 1/ (z \cos z)^\prime_{z = -\pi/2}$ = $-\pi/2$.

Thus by Cauchy residue theorem

$\frac{i}{4- \pi}\int_{C} \frac{1}{z \cos z} = \frac{i}{4- \pi}2\pi i \left[1 - \pi/2 - \pi/2\right] = \frac{-2\pi}{4-\pi} (1-\pi) \neq 2$. Could anybody help me to discover where I went wrong. I would be very much grateful to you.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. The residues at $\pm \pi/2$ are the reciprocals of your results:
$$\mbox{Res}(f(z),\pm\pi/2) =\left. \frac{1}{(z\cos(z))'}\right|_{z=\pm\pi/2}=
\left. \frac{1}{\cos(z)-z\sin(z)}\right|_{z=\pm\pi/2}=-\frac{2}{\pi}.$$

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I am sorry, I didn't understand what you mean by saying that residues are reciprocal.

Comment: See my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you very very much. I just forgot that $1$ is there in the numerator also. I got the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using $C=4e^{i[0,2\pi]}$, that is $|z|=4$ in a counter-clockwise direction.
$$
\int_C\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z\cos(z)}\tag{1}
$$
There are three singularities inside $C$: $\left\{0,\pm\frac\pi2\right\}$, all of them simple.

At $z=0$, the residue is $1$. Since $\cos(z)=\sin\left(\frac\pi2\pm z\right)$, at $z=\pm\frac\pi2$, the residue is $-\frac2\pi$

The sum of all these residues is $1-\frac4\pi$. Therefore, the integral in $(1)$ is $(2\pi-8)i$. Thus,
$$
\frac i{4-\pi}\int_C\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{z\cos(z)}=2\tag{2}
$$
As pointed out by Robert Z, the problem seems to be the residues at $\pm\frac\pi2$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I am blessed to use MathSE.